# Rails method to add record to db from the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails I'd like to know how can I create a method to add the parameters from the URL to the database?

e.g. `http://localhost:3000/myapp?name=John&age=32/`

How can I insert the name parameter and then the age parameter into the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you could do (Given you crated a User model + it's migration):

```
User.create({:name => params[:name], :age => params[:age].to_i})
```

name and age attributes should be set as accessible in the User model.

But you should have a look at how the scaffold behave and also look at [railsforzombies.org](http://railsforzombies.org) where you'll learn much!

Comment: yeah, he better checks out a tutorial or the Rails guides. That's explained in the first chapter of any tutorial! and in the Rails way you will write simply "User.create(params[:user])"